# JQUERY - Filtering a single column with multiple checkboxes selected with datatables

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

Checkbox Filtering a column with multiple values based on selected checkbox. The problem is the regex used in my search won't display all the values selected as indicated with the red line. Help will be appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT 2: A more detailed codes

Below is the initialization of my DataTable 1.10

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

        //jQuery DataTables initialization 
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show processing bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process on server side
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multi column order
            "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // for hide default global search box // little confusion? don't worry I explained in the tutorial website
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/home/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "FName", "name": "FName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "MName", "name": "MName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "LName", "name": "LName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Email", "name": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Country", "name": "Country", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Gender", "name": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Age", "name": "Age", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "School", "name": "School", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "SkillName", "name": "SkillName", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Rating", "name": "Rating", "autoWidth": true },
            ]
        });
              
              oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="csharp" name="skill" value="C#" />C
<input type="checkbox" id="cplus" name="skill" value="C++" />C++
<input type="checkbox" id="android" name="skill" value="Android" />Android
<input type="checkbox" id="java" name="skill" value="Java" />Java
```

Below is the search function of my DataTable using checkboxes

```
  $("input[type='checkbox'").bind("change", function (event, ui) { // reads every changes in the state of checkboxes when selected

        var types = $('input:checkbox[name="skill"]:checked').map(function () { //reads the value of the selected checkboxes
            return this.value;        //Returns the value of the selected checkboxes

        //START OF THE PROBLEM

        }).get().join('|');           //Concatinates the values of the checkboxes selected
                                      //Example: C#|C++     it will search the records that contains a skill of C# and C++


        //Below is where the searching will occur where it reads the value of types as a regex. 
        //But the problem is, this line below does not read 'var types' as a regex.
        //When two checkboxes are selected (example: C#|C++), it does not read as 'C# OR C++'.
        //The result is that no data will match for the value of var types = 'C#|C++' since it does not read it as a regex.

        oTable.column(8).search(types, true, false, false).draw();

        //END OF THE PROBLEM

        alert(types); //Tracing for the value of types when a checkbox is selected
    });
```

IMPORTANT: This is my source for the search using RegEx. The difference is that I used the latest API for DataTable. http://plnkr.co/edit/b8cLVaVlbNKOQhDwI2mw?p=preview

Comment: Dude, no pictures please.

Comment: To be honest, it's still not clear enough, include more details, like the checkbox parts (not necessary all of them) and explain what you want to achieve when doing the checking for example.

Comment: Is `$("input[type='checkbox'")` missing a closing square bracket `]`?

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup I added a more detailed code. Tell me what you think sir. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pang nope it's working fine. No problem on that line of code.

Comment: When adding a code snippet, please make sure that it is functional—you have forgotten to load the jQuery DataTables plugin in your snippet, so it will not work anyway, defeating the purpose of having a snippet at the first place.